# How do I get a notification from tekton pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, devops, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I now have a tekton pipeline and I want to get a notification when one task in the pipeline is completed or on error. I would like the notification is a Http request to my own service just like the jenkins notification webhook so that I can save the status of every task in my pipeline.

I have seen that there is something called cloud event in the documentation of tekton. I tried to deploy the configMap just like what the documentation said [here](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/additional-configs/#configuring-cloudevents-notifications), but it seems not work. And if I did not misunderstand, tekton pipeline seems only to send an event of the pipeline status. Is there any way to feel the status of the tasks in the pipeline?